# Did anyone manage to make katmouse work over vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

As you might know katmouse enables scrolling over non active windows. Which would be especially great in vs 2010 because now you can take source code windows to other monitors. But of course it does not work. Is there a trick to make WPF receive the right message?

Answer (score 3):

Try [WizMouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/), remember to set it to run with administrator privileges to make it work for admin level windows.

Comment: I've been using KatMouse for years and cursed the lack of VS mutliwindow support.  WizMouse worked perfectly.  thanks.

Comment: Blame microsoft, it's such piss poor usability, especially when modal windows prevent you from focusing the window you want to scroll. My guess is that they still have not fixed this in Windows 8. /rant

Answer (score 2):

Yes, well, mostly.

Open the KatMouse dialog by right clicking and choosing settings.  Go to the Classes tab, and drag the icon on the bottom of the dialog to an open vs2010 window.  That'll add the new class to KatMouse.  Now double click that new entry to bring up the settings for that class, and turn off the "Window has wheel scrolling support" checked box.

Unfortunately it seems like the class name changes for every source window, so I think you have tell KatMouse about every source window every time you launch vs. :(

Comment: This still doesn't work for autohide dialogs or multiple tabs.